# Assigning a variable with the contents of a file

Tags: string, bash, batch-file, cmd, scripting

Does anyone know how to assign to a variable (from a batch `/fisier.bat` script) the contents of another file (`file.txt`). -CMD Windows

Comment: bash or batch? (Unix or Windows)? Whats the content of the textfile?

Comment: Windows. Testfile is a name

Comment: Then it's batch, not bash. Fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

this gets the first line of a file into a variable:

```
<file.txt set /p "var="
echo %var%
```